# unity3d не работает OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
    if(collision.gameObject.tag=="Fire")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

объект отмечен как триггер - при прохождении через этот коллайдер-триггер на котором висит этот скрипт - другие коллайдеры должны уничтожаться.
На этот спрайт также помимо коллайдера добавлен и Rigidbody2d

Comment: Что за глупый вопрос приведением стандартного кода? Из без этого кода есть куча способов сделать коллизию не рабочей. Вроде рейтинг не маленький, а вопрос задать правильно не научились. Конкретики надо, матрица коллизий, два обьекта, которые должны колизиться,  как минимум скрины этого нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял:

Есть объект с `BoxCollider2d (triger)` и `Rigidbody2d`, на котором весит скрипт с вашим кодом. Есть еще какие-нибудь объекты с `BoxCollider2d (triger)` и тегом `Fire`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при эмм прикосновении к первому объекту эти `Fire` уничтожались.
Код правильный, возможные причины, почему не работает:

1. в теге объекта `Fire` не совпадает с `Fire` из скрипта (короче, ошибка в слове).
2. у `Rigidbody2d` отключена `Simulated`.
   Дальше просто не стал экспериментировать. В повешенном на объекте `Rigidbody2d` ничего не менял, в `BoxCollider2d` тоже, только триггером сделал, сработало сразу